# Solving a Perturbed Cubic Equation

Tags: asymptotics, roots, perturbation-theory, cubics

Consider a cubic equation

$(1 + \epsilon)x^3 - 2ax^2 + (a - 3\epsilon)x + 2\epsilon = 0$

where $\epsilon > 0$ and $a \gg 1$.

In the limit of $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$,

$x(x^2 - 2ax + a) = 0$

so that

$ x_0 = a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - a} \approx 2a$ or $1/2 + 1/(8a)$.

I want to find approximate solutions to the cubic equation, which is accurate even for $\epsilon \sim a$. For $x_0 \approx 2a \gg 1$, the balancing between the third and second order terms just gives

$x \approx 2a/(1+\epsilon)$

which is found to be quite accurate when $\epsilon \sim a$.

For the other solution, I tried expanding the solution from $x_0$.

$x = x_0 + x_1$

and kept the terms first order in $x_1$ to obtain

$3\epsilon x_0^2x_1 - 3\epsilon x_1 -4a x_0 x_1 + a x_1 + 3 x_0^2 x_1 + 2\epsilon = 0$

or since $a \gg 1$, $x_0 \approx 1/2$ so $x_1 = 2\epsilon/a$.

Comparing $x = x_0 + x_1$ with the exact solution, however, I found that the approximation becomes inaccurate when $\epsilon \sim a$.

Can anyone help me how to attack this problem?

Comment: Considering the envisaged range of $\epsilon$ this is not a "perturbation" of a  given cubic equation, but simply an equation with two arbitrary parameters, namely $a$ and $\epsilon$. It is impossible to give a single expansion valid in the full range, short of solving the equation exactly.

Comment: Having examined the full solution by varying $\epsilon$ from $\epsilon \ll 1$ to $\epsilon \sim a$, I have to agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Why not considering $$F(x,\epsilon)=(1 + \epsilon)x^3 - 2ax^2 + (a - 3\epsilon)x + 2\epsilon = 0$$ and use implicit differentiation to obtain the value of $\frac{dx}{d\epsilon}$ and compute its value for $\epsilon=0$ and then use $$x \simeq x_0+\frac{dx}{d\epsilon} \Delta \epsilon$$

For sure, you must do the above for each of the roots $$x_1=0$$ $$x_2=a-\sqrt{a^2-a}$$  $$x_3=a+\sqrt{a^2-a}$$ I strongly recommend that you leave the roots as they are above, compute the corresponding $\frac{dx_i}{d\epsilon}$ for each of the roots (setting $\epsilon=0$) and expand from this point.

For sure, you could do what alex.jordan suggested; his solution is more rigorous than mine but it will be quite tedious even to have the first order expansion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to approximate using implicit derivative but to no avail.
$dF=((1+\epsilon)3x^2 - 4ax + (a-3\epsilon))dx + (x^3 - 3x + 2)d\epsilon = 0$

Comment: $dx/d\epsilon = (-x^3 +3x - 2)/(3x^2(1+\epsilon) -4ax + (a-3\epsilon) \rightarrow (-x^3 +3x - 2)/(3x^2-4ax+a) \rightarrow -5/(8a)$. In the last expression, I plugged in $x_0 \approx 1/2$ and assumed $a \gg x_0$. This gives negative coefficient for $dx/d\epsilon$ but the numerical (exact) solution shows that $x_0$ slightly increases from $1/2 + 1/(8a)$ as $\epsilon$ increases. Am I making any mistake?

Comment: It works very well. If you have problem, tell me !

Comment: As I told you, make everything rigorous till the end. Moreover, your approximations of the $x_i$ may be not sufficient. One of the roots is $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8 a}+\frac{1}{16
   a^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^3\right)$$ and the second is $$2 a-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8 a}-\frac{1}{16
   a^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^3\right)$$

Comment: I have to go now. If you want me to elaborate, tell me. I should be back in 16 hours from now.

Comment: Ahhh..seems like I missed a term. Now Everything's fine. Thank you again!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are told that $a\gg1$ and $\epsilon$ can be about anything one could write $a:={1\over q}$ with $0<q\ll1$, where $q$ is considered a small parameter. Writing $t$ instead of $\epsilon$ the equation then becomes
$$x-2x^2+\bigl((1+t)x^3-3tx+2t\bigr)\>q=0\ .\tag{1}$$
Letting $q=0$ here we obtain the two solutions $x=0$ and $x={1\over2}$. We therefore introduce the expansions
$$x(q)=\sum_{k\geq1} c_k q^k,\qquad y(q)={1\over2}+\sum_{k\geq1} d_k q^k\ .$$
with undetermined coefficients $c_k$, resp. $d_k\>$. Entering these into $(1)$ and comparing coefficients (I used Mathematica for this) one obtains
$$\eqalign{x(q)&=-2 tq  + 2 t^2q^2 - 10 t^3 q^3 + (8 t^3 + 66 t^4) q^4 + 
  (-64 t^4 - 434 t^5) q^5\ +?q^6\ ,\cr
y(q) &= {1\over2} +   {1 + 5 t\over8}q +  {1 - 2 t - 35 t^2\over16} q^2 + 
  {5 - 9 t + 111 t^2 + 1405 t^3\over128}q^3 \ + ?q^4\ .\cr}$$
The third root, whose  order of magnitude is $a$, cannot be obtained in this way. Maybe writing $x:=a\>\xi$ with a new unknown $\xi$ will do the job. I leave this to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could find all three roots exactly using the cubic formula/cubic-solving process, expand the roots as series in $\epsilon$ and then cut them off at whatever order you like.

The formula for one of the real roots is [here](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/). To get the other two roots multiply the giant cube roots by $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ respectively, and then in the other order, where $\omega$ is a complex root of unity.

Comment: Your solution is much more rigorous than mine but it would be very tedious to get even the first order expansion (I did it !). Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Agreed. Maybe this should have been a comment. I really was just checking OP was aware of the exact cubic solutions.